# Grabbing json data securely

Tags: json

So I am using this API which allows me to grab data from a database to display on my website using json and javascript. I am trying to figure out how to secure my API key. They said you can use java or C# to make a call and then display the json data using javascript? So basically the idea is that I use a separate scripting language (c# or java I think PHP works too?) to make the call and then take the results and display them client sided so that the API key is hidden in server sided code.

I have NO clue how I am supposed to do this. Does anyone know how this could be done in theory?

Comment: It would help if you showed us your code, but in a general sense, no matter what programming language you use, if you issue an HTTP based POST request, the content can be seen while traveling. You would want to use HTTPS based requests and try to put the API key into the post request.

Comment: You can create a simple NodeJS application to fetch the data on the server, with a request library like [request](https://github.com/request/request) where your API key is secure, then serve that data to your application with [Express](http://expressjs.com/). Your client application would fetch the data from your Node server.

Comment: Yes you can use a server app to query and return JSON. It will be a Web Server (and can also serve your JavaScript pages and resources). It hosts the API key and might cache the returned data or stream it. However not sure if the question isnt too broad to explain the details.

Comment: Yeah I can't actually install anything using NPM because I don't have root access on the server. I've been trying to do it with PHP in order to shy away from javascript.

This is my code currently:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EWwUWBkY

See how the API key would be placed in plaintext for anyone who can see the javascript file? It needs to be somehow server sided.

Comment: @E.S.: As I understand it, this is about not exposing the API key in client-side code (and therefor using a server-side technique to fetch the data from the API, using the key, and then use JS on the client to fetch it from the server) – so HTTP vs HTTPS has little to do with it. The API key stays on the server, and does not get transported between the server and the site visitors browser.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Java and C# are not scripting languages. They are high-level programming languages.
2. Addressing the code you posted on pastebin, you cannot make an AJAX call to another website. This creates a cross-origin request which is not allowed by most browsers. The goal of blocking cross-origin requests is to prevent malicious code "from interfering with the operation of benign web sites" (as the RFC 6454 published by the IETF puts it).

Aside from that though, what you are asking for is entirely possible. The simplest way to do it would be query say some PHP script `call_api.php` with the API link to call. So (copying from your pastebin code), let's say you want to call: `https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/<Some ID>?api_key=<Your API Key>`. Rather than querying this link, you could send something like `api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/<Some ID>` as a parameter to `call_api.php`.

`call_api.php` could be set up as follows:

```
<?php
$_API_KEY = "Your secret API key.";

$requestSuffix = $_REQUEST['suffix']; // This is whatever the API request is
                                      // E.g., "api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/..."

$requestURL = "https://na.api.pvp.net" . ($requestSuffix[0] != '/' ? '/' : '' ) . $requestSuffix;

// Now we need to add the secret API to the end of the request URL:
if(strpos($requestSuffix, '?') === False){
    // We just need to tack on "?api_key..."
    $requestURL .= "?api_key=$_API_KEY";
}else{
    // The requested suffix already has a '?' and thus it potentially has
    // some parameters already
    if(substr($requestURL, -1) == '?'){
        // There's just a blank '?' on the end without any parameters yet.
        $requestURL .= "api_key=$_API_KEY";
    }else{
        // The request suffix likely already contains some parameters
        // So we'll just add the api key as another parameter
        $requestURL .= "&api_key=$_API_KEY";
    }
}

// Now with our request URL constructed, we're ready to make the request
$ch = curl_init($requestURL);

// Set the cURL options:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); // don't show header in output
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true); // prevent cached connections
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true); // Don't pool connection for reuse

// Execute the request:
// (by default the response will be directly printed to the output stream or buffer)
curl_exec($ch);

// Make sure the connection is closed to free up resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

So you just put this on your website's server and then you can call this script using AJAX providing it the the `suffix` parameter (path and possibly parameters that you would like to use as your query to `na.api.pvp.net`).